# Reuse the Proposition in other sections

Tags: theorems

In Section 1, I defined a proposition and I want to add proof in other sections, say Appendix, how can I reuse the number without generating a new number of proposition?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
 \newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
 \usepackage{chngcntr}
 \begin{document}
 
 \begin{proposition}
   This is a proposition
 \end{proposition}

  \appendix
  % add my proof to this part
 \end{document}
```

Comment: I suppose that, before the proof itself, in the appendix, you would restate the proposition, with the same number?

Comment: @Bernard, exactly. Right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `thm-restate` package that comes with `thmtools`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools, thm-restate}
\declaretheorem[name=Proposition]{proposition}
\usepackage{chngcntr}

\begin{document}

 \begin{restatable}{proposition}{Firstprop}
   This is a proposition.
 \end{restatable}

\appendix
\section{Proofs}
\Firstprop*
  \begin{proof}
  add my proof to this part \qedhere
\end{proof}

\section{More results}
\begin{proposition}
  This is another proposition.
\end{proposition}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\begin{document}
\begin{proposition}\label{prop:simple}
This is a simple proposition
\end{proposition}
\appendix
\section*{Proof od Proposition~\ref{prop:simple}}
Here is the proof.
\end{document}
```

If you want to restate the Proposition, have a look at the `thmtools` package. If you want to add style to your new theorems, have a look at the `ntheorem` package.